# How to force Resharper to generate property under the constructor?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

Whenever I'm trying with Resharper to generate property from a constructor value:

[image]

Then the property is always generated above the constructor:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Value { get; }

    public MyClass(int value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }
}
```

Is there any way how to force Resharper to generate them under the constructor?

**EDIT:**

My file layout settings seems to be OK:

[image]

Comment: I _think_ you may be able to do it by activating the sorting, but I'm not able to test it right now hence a comment. ReSharper > Options > Code Editing > C# > File Layout. Move Constructor to the top, or wherever you want it.

Comment: @Equalsk thanks for the comment. I have also noticed this settings, but here the layout is sorted as required (first constructor, then properties...)

Comment: Yes, fields are generated ok, but I was asking about properties.

Comment: Yeah, I realised my mistake two moments later, oops. It's weird, I get the same behaviour, ReSharper totally ignores my XAML specifying constructors above all else.

Comment: try clean up code. that should work, you can create custom clean up setting to only change ordering of elements. (no change in code style)

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary, thanks this one helps, but I still think that Resharper should care about layout during code generation.

Comment: Indeed, you can report and send feedback to resharper team. Goto resharper menu> help>send feedback or report problem

Comment: ok, good idea. thanks

Answer (score 2):

After the property is generated above the constructor, put the cursor somewhere on the property and hit Ctrl+Shift+Alt+J to move it below the constructor. This works for me in Visual Studio 2019 16.5.4 with ReSharper 2020.1.2.

Comment: Just discovered this jewel - thx! tried and discovered that Ctl+Shift+Alt+K moves up BTW